# Spacemacs - is theere a way to use downloaded theme for spacemacs (.el file)

Tags: spacemacs

I'm new to spacemacs/emacs.  I downloaded an theme file .el and put it in /private/themes dir. (themes dir I created)  How can I see it when I hit M-x - load theme ?  I read some articles about using add-to list load-path and require but dont know how to use it and where to place these instrcutions in the .spacemacs file.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I Do this in .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(custom-set-variables
  '(custom-enabled-themes '(spolsky))) -> loaded at startup
```

I think also that we can put the theme file inside ~/.emacs.d/etc/themes so that they are view as safe by emacs.  Simply use M-x load-theme after.